# Unexpected Identifier Error after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have this HTML code:

```
 <div id="texttheory" class="centertext">'. $short .' </div>';
 <button id="thbutton" class="theory_button" onclick="javascript:changetheory('.$long.')">
     <img id="imagebutton" src="./images/arrows.png" width="15px" heigth="22px">
 </button>
```

which I produce inside a php script called by a javascript function:

```
function showTheory (kl) {
     var xmlhttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                 document.getElementById("theory").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","gettheory.php?kl="+kl,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

The function changetheory is in a js library properly included in html head tag and it works like this:

```
function changetheory (content, old) {
     document.getElementById("texttheory").innerHTML= content;
     document.getElementById("thbutton").setAttribute ('onclick', "javascript:changetheory("+old+", "+content+")");
}
```

when i click on the thbutton to switch the two text i get error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 
on line 1 of the html file.
Anyone can see what's the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing quotes around the content string for the onclick event.

```
<button id="thbutton" class="theory_button" onclick="javascript:changetheory('.$long.')">
```

Should be

```
<button id="thbutton" class="theory_button" onclick="javascript:changetheory(\''.$long.'\')">
```

Comment: very thank you pal. i feel a little dummy right now! :) I will accept the answer as soon as i'll be allowed to!